# Using groovy to append to a certain line number in a file

Tags: groovy

Rather than appending to the end of a file, I am trying to replace or append to a certain line using groovy `File` manipulation.

Is there a method to do this?
`append` adds to end of file while write overwrites existing file:

```
def file = new File("newFilename")
file.append("I wish to append this to line 8")
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a line-aware Groovy file-handling library; should be able to use normal Java libraries (default or third-party) though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small files you can use the following piece of code:

```
def f = new File('file')
def lines = f.readLines()
lines = lines.plus(7, "I'm a new line!")
f.text = lines.join('\n')
```

Comment: that looks like it would add a new line 8, instead of appending to the current line 8.

Comment: @billjamesdev, it doesn't matter. It just shows the general approach.

Answer (score 5):

In general, with Java and Groovy file handling, you can only append to the end of files.  There is no way to insert information, although you can overwrite data anywhere without shifting the position of what follows.

This means that to append to a specific line that is not at the end of the file you need to rewrite the whole file.

For example:

```
def file = new File("newFilename")
new File("output").withPrintWriter { out ->
    def linenumber = 1
    file.eachLine { line ->
        if (linenumber == 8)
            out.print(line)
            out.println("I wish to append this to line 8")
        } else {
            out.println(line)
        }
        linenumber += 1
    }
}
```